# Why was my question killed without discussion?

Tags: discussion

I asked a question about installing windows 8 on a smartphone which was closed as a duplicate.

When I rephrased the question and asked for it to be reopened Joe locked the question saying that it would be discussed on the meta site.

When I asked why it was not being discussed someone, presumably joe deleted the question.

Why is a moderator acting in such a fashion, it really is very poor standards. When someone asks an awkward question the repsonse should be to politely answer them, not treat them like a pariah, and throw them out of the system.

Answer (score 2):

The comment didn't say it *was going to be* discussed, but, "This *can be* discussed ..."

It is normal for questions that are closed to be deleted as a matter of course, as long as nobody has voted to reopen the question.

It was event suggested (by a non-moderator, as well) that you "have two quite separate questions here and as such it should be broken up", but it doesn't appear that you've done that. If you really do feel that you have a question that could be answered differently to the accepted answer to [Lance's question](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/676/106) without promoting illegal activity, then I'd suggest you could ask it again, albeit with perhaps clearer phrasing.

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry how that question played out. I had to lock it because the duplicate text kept being edited out of the question, and the excessive flagging that was going one. The question walks the line on being a duplicate, and I felt that it was close enough to the original that it is a duplicate.

I want you to know that I wasn't acting alone. I had talked to the other moderators in the stack exchange network and they were advising me on what to do here.

I left a comment on your question letting you know it can be discussed here, or on the chat if you would like. Should the community as a whole feel like it is significantly different than the original than it would be re-opened, no questions asked.

I don't know why the question was deleted. I can look into it, but I think the system might have done it during a cleanup phase.

Comment: Yes. Sometimes the `Community` bot user does things stranges but according to common behaviors for every question.

Comment: I edited the question twice to try and make the distinction clearer and flagged it each time. If thats what you think of as 'excessive' then I think you're being unreasonable. a question needs a bit longer, especially on a beta site to garner some answers. Locking it was a knee jerk reaction.

Comment: @ClaraOnager I looked into it and your question wasn't deleted by the system. Another moderator did it. If you still feel like the question is significantly different than [this one](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/676/106) create a meta post about it.